# How to keep video and lesson menu same height

Tags: css

I'm trying to do a video layout like the following:
[image: layout mockup]

The video embed will be with an iframe. I'd like to keep the height of lesson items on the left to be same height as the video and to have different container on the bottom that comes after the video and lesson container.

html

```
<div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='video-container'>
      <iframe class='iframe' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/I2UBjN5ER4s" width="640" height="360" frameBorder="0" 
          allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowFullScreen title="https://player.vimeo.com/video/459785420">

          </iframe>
    </div>
    <div class='menu-items'>
      <div class='lesson'>
        lesson menu
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
}

.video-container {
  overflow: hidden; 
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  flex: 0 0 75%;
}

.iframe {
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
  }

.menu-items {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 0 0 25;
}

.lesson {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

I've created a codepen: https://codepen.io/cagaroos/pen/XWdoROw?editors=1100

Comment: The codepen is empty :(

Comment: If you're going to set your video to always be 360px height then you can just set your `.container` to be 360px height also.

Comment: I've updated the codepen @RayeesAC

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.video-container {
  height: auto;
}
```

instead of

```
.video-container {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
}
```

add bottom and right

```
.iframe {
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

remove `padding-bottom` of last `lesson` div

```
.lesson:last-child {
  padding-bottom:0;
}
```

also remove **width** and **height** `<iframe>` tag in html

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/Vwaqbom)

Comment: Are you like this @Abdi?

Comment: Slightly solves the problem, if I add more menu items, the video container expands. I wanted to make the menu item container scrollable.